# How to convert a java applet to a console application?

Tags: java, applet, console-application

I have a task to divide two numbers and get result like on picture:

[image: long division]

I did this task using applet but mentor asked to get rid of it and do the task as a console application. How do I convert the applet to a console application.

Comment: So which bit is actually causing you problems? I assume they don't actually require a *picture*... you should be able to take the logic in your applet and just write out the relevant values to the console.

Comment: Good decision getting rid of Applet.  But can you share any Java code which you have already attempted?

Comment: in order to do that I need to underline numbers and I cant find how to do that without applet.

Comment: What you actually have to do is print underscores (`_`), on the line below the number, or use box-drawing characters from Unicode. Some consoles support underlines, but it's not a standard feature.

Comment: *"I did this task using applet but mentor asked to get rid of it and do the task as a console application."* That's a good instructor. Programmers should understand the language basics before delving into apps. with a GUI. And applets are dead: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).